# 1-Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have faced this problem while working on project, I can't understand how to fix this problem

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MoviesByReleaseDate",
    url: "movies/byreleasedate/{year}/{month}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Movies",
        action = "ByReleaseDate",      
    },
    new  { year = @"/d={4}", month = @"/d={2}" }   
);
```

Comment: areyou using optional parameter in your code . Please cshare you code then it will be helpful to answer

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLvJn.png

Comment: @HashimAttari: Would you mind pasting up the code inline? Else I think this question could be deleted which somewhat wastes the time of the answerer.

Comment: @HashimAttari paste code here with formatting . it will make ur question easy to undrstand.

Comment: When you are passing named arguments like `name`, `url`, and `defaults`, you need to put those at the end of your parameter list. Right now you have those named arguments and then an unnamed argument in the form of your anonymous object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You call the `MapRoute` method with 3 named arguments (`name`, `url`, `defaults`) and the fourth argument is unnamed, which is not allowed.

Either name also the last argument or use only unnamed ones in the same order as it is specified in the `MapRoute` method.

See some explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use multiple arguments to your MapRoute method, you can just don't specified the name of the other arguments like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "MoviesByReleaseDate",
            "movies/byreleasedate/{year}/{month}",
            new { controller = "Movies", action = "ByReleaseDate" }, 
            new { year = @"\d{4}", month = @"\d{2}" }
            );
```